# Extending Domestic Reservation in the US

Tags: bookings, domestic-travel, schedule-change

Suppose a passenger is in the USA and has booked a round trip reservation leaving from New York City to Miami. Here are some notes:

1. He is leaving New York City on July 5.
2. He is coming back from Miami on July 8.

If he wants to extend this trip to July 14, what would be the additional cost he would have to pay to make this change?

Comment: Have you tried asking the travel company concerned? I don’t see how anyone on TSE can answer this question unless you provide more detail

Comment: Without knowing the airline and the type of fare, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 5):

There's no real way of knowing. You haven't even said what mode of transportation this reservation is by. Assuming an airline, there are two possible components:

- **Change fee**. This is a fee the airline charges for making changes to your ticket. Many major US airlines have waived or eliminated these for many domestic flights, but that doesn't apply universally or sometimes to their cheapest "basic" fares. You can look up the change fee policy for your airline.
- **Difference in fare**. Your new flight on the 14th may cost more if purchased now. It's a more short notice booking and seats may be scarce, so the airline may charge more. The airline will charge you this difference in fare. There's no way to know what this is without asking, as it depends on the airline's current prices for flights from Miami to New York City on July 14th. It's even possible the new fare will be less, and some airlines will give you back a credit toward future travel in this case.

The only way to know is to contact the airline (either by telephone or by using the "change your flight" feature of their website if available) and to price out different options, as it will depend on the fares available for each possible flight on the 14th.

Comment: Note that the change fee may vary depending on the fare of the original flight. In most cases, the easiest option is to use the “manage my booking” section of the airline where you should be able to see the options and relevant prices.